# Notes feature in Line chart MVC wrapper not displaying

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to use the Notes feature to add text to plotted points in my Line chart. When I try setting the `Format()` or `Template()` expecting the value to be populated by the bound value nothing displays.  If I set the `Text()` field to a some string value, the text is displayed as expected.

```c#
 series.Line(d => d.Revenue)
     .Notes(notes => notes.Label(label => label.Position(ChartNoteLabelPosition.Outside).Format("{0:C0}")).Position(ChartNotePosition.Top))
     .Name("Revenue").Color("#00326f")
     .Labels(labels => labels.Position(ChartPointLabelsPosition.Above).Format("{0:C0}")).Visible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you replace the first line of your sample with:

```
series.Line(d => d.Revenue, null, d => d.Revenue)
```